# Extract url params in ruby

Tags: ruby, url, parameters

I would like to extract parameters from url. I have following path pattern:

```
pattern = "/foo/:foo_id/bar/:bar_id"
```

And example url:

```
url = "/foo/1/bar/2"
```

I would like to get {foo_id: 1, bar_id: 2}. I tried to convert pattern into something like this:

```
"\/foo\/(?<foo_id>.*)\/bar\/(?<bar_id>.*)"
```

I failed on first step when I wanted to replace backslash in url:

```
formatted = pattern.gsub("/", "\/")
```

Do you know how to fix this gsub? Maybe you know better solution to do this.

EDIT:
It is plain Ruby. I am not using RoR.

Comment: You have to skip backslash. try this `gsub("/", "\\/")`

Comment: You only need to escape slashes in a Regexp literal (`/foo\/bar/`). If you're defining a Regexp from a string you don't need to (`Regexp.new("foo/bar")`). (You can check this yourself using the built-in `Regexp.escape`. `Regexp.escape("foo/bar")` returns `"foo/bar"`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said above, you only need to escape slashes in a Regexp literal, e.g. `/foo\/bar/`. When defining a Regexp from a string it's not necessary: `Regexp.new("foo/bar")` produces the same Regexp as `/foo\/bar/`.

As to your larger problem, here's how I'd solve it, which I'm guessing is pretty much how you'd been planning to solve it:

```
PATTERN_PART_MATCH = /:(\w+)/
PATTERN_PART_REPLACE = '(?<\1>.+?)'

def pattern_to_regexp(pattern)
  expr = Regexp.escape(pattern) # just in case
           .gsub(PATTERN_PART_MATCH, PATTERN_PART_REPLACE)
  Regexp.new(expr)
end

pattern = "/foo/:foo_id/bar/:bar_id"
expr = pattern_to_regexp(pattern)
# => /\/foo\/(?<foo_id>.+?)\/bar\/(?<bar_id>.+?)/

str = "/foo/1/bar/2"
expr.match(str)
# => #<MatchData "/foo/1/bar/2" foo_id:"1" bar_id:"2">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
regex = /\/foo\/(?<foo_id>.*)\/bar\/(?<bar_id>.*)/i
matches = "/foo/1/bar/2".match(regex)
Hash[matches.names.zip(matches[1..-1])]
```

IRB output:

```
2.3.1 :032 > regex = /\/foo\/(?<foo_id>.*)\/bar\/(?<bar_id>.*)/i
 => /\/foo\/(?<foo_id>.*)\/bar\/(?<bar_id>.*)/i
2.3.1 :033 > matches = "/foo/1/bar/2".match(regex)
 => #<MatchData "/foo/1/bar/2" foo_id:"1" bar_id:"2">
2.3.1 :034 > Hash[matches.names.zip(matches[1..-1])]
 => {"foo_id"=>"1", "bar_id"=>"2"}
```

I'd advise reading this article on how Rack parses query params.  The above works for your example you gave, but is not extensible for other params.

http://codefol.io/posts/How-Does-Rack-Parse-Query-Params-With-parse-nested-query

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, the foo id and bar id will be dynamic.

```
require 'json'

#url to scan
    url = "/foo/1/bar/2"
#scanning ids from url
    id = url.scan(/\d/)
#gsub method to replacing values from url
    url_with_id = url.gsub(url, "{foo_id: #{id[0]}, bar_id: #{id[1]}}")

#output    
    => "{foo_id: 1, bar_id: 2}"
```

If you want to change string to hash

```
url_hash = eval(url_with_id)

=>{:foo_id=>1, :bar_id=>2}
```